# Dodge nested data points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting 12 data points that are nested across two grouping levels called `type` and `treatment`. The group `type` includes the options `many` and `few`, while the group `treatment` includes the options `low` and `high`. As such, each of the four combinations occurs three times.

The code for the figure is as follows (requires package ggplot2):

```
p20 <-
ggplot(data = test2, lty.est = 1) +
geom_point(data = subset(test2, treatment == 'low'), aes(class, value, shape = type,
                                                           group = type, colour=treatment),
         stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
geom_point(data = subset(test2, treatment == 'high'), aes(class, value, shape = type, 
                                                          group = type, colour=treatment),
         stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17)) +
geom_errorbar(data = subset(test2, treatment == 'low'), aes(class, ymin=value-se, width = 0.2,
                                                              ymax=value+se, group = type, 
                                                              colour = treatment), stat = 'identity', 
            position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
 geom_errorbar(data = subset(test2, treatment == 'high'), aes(class,     ymin=value-se, width = 0.2,
                                                             ymax=value+se, group = type, 
                                                             colour = treatment), stat = 'identity', 
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
xlab("Class") +
ylab("Value") +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.0,0.0),
                 limits=c(8.25, 10.25),
                 breaks=c(8.5,9,9.5,10),
                 labels=c("8.5","9","9.5","10")) +
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("one", "five", "ten"),
               labels=c("One", "Five", "Ten")) +
theme_bw() +
#  theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.4)) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1,face="bold", size=16),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0.1, size=14, angle=0)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.70, face="bold", size=18),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=14)) +
theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
theme(panel.border = element_rect(size=2, colour = "black", fill=NA, linetype=1)) +
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.3,0.4,0.28,0.0),"lines"))
```

[image]

What I would like to have changed in the current figure is the relative position of points. For example, the arrangement of the plots for each ‘Class’ should be (from left to right): few high, few low, many high and many low.

Any advice on how to adjust the code accordingly would be greatly appreciated.

Please find the data below:

```
> dput(test2)
structure(list(type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("few", "many"), class = "factor"), 
class = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("five", "one", "ten"), class = "factor"), 
treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("high", "low"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(8.64, 8.78, 9.64, 9.87, 9.93, 9.99, 8.79, 8.93, 
9.69, 9.91, 9.98, 9.98), se = c(0.14, 0.13, 0.09, 0.05, 0.03, 
0.01, 0.13, 0.11, 0.08, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02)), .Names = c("type", 
"class", "treatment", "value", "se"), class = "data.frame", row.names =  c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the `interaction` function. With:

```
ggplot(data = test2) +
  geom_point(aes(class, value, shape = type, group = interaction(treatment,type), colour=treatment),
             stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width=0.5), size = 2.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(class, ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se, group = interaction(treatment,type), colour = treatment),
                stat = 'identity', position=position_dodge(width=0.5), width = 0.2) +
  labs(x="Class", y="Value") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("one", "five", "ten"), labels=c("One", "Five", "Ten")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.0,0.0), limits=c(8.25, 10.25), breaks=c(8.5,9,9.5,10), labels=c("8.5","9","9.5","10")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1,face="bold", size=16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0.1, size=14, angle=0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.70, face="bold", size=18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(size=2, colour = "black", fill=NA, linetype=1),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.3,0.4,0.28,0.0),"lines"))
```

you get:

[image]

---

Another option is to create a interaction variable beforehand:

```
test2$treattype <- factor(interaction(test2$treatment,test2$type),
                          labels = c("few high","few low","many high","many low"))
```

With:

```
ggplot(data = test2) +
  geom_point(aes(class, value, shape = treattype, colour = treattype),
             stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width=0.5), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(class, ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se, colour = treattype),
                stat = 'identity', position=position_dodge(width=0.5), width = 0.2) +
  labs(x="Class", y="Value") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("one", "five", "ten"), labels=c("One", "Five", "Ten")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.0,0.0), limits=c(8.25, 10.25), breaks=c(8.5,9,9.5,10), labels=c("8.5","9","9.5","10")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","blue","red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17,16,17)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1,face="bold", size=16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0.1, size=14, angle=0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.70, face="bold", size=18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(size=2, colour = "black", fill=NA, linetype=1),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.3,0.4,0.28,0.0),"lines"))
```

you get a plot in which you have just one legend:

[image]

---

The following option is an extension of the solution offered by @jlhoward and also deals with the fact that the errorbars for class "ten" are hardly readable and integrates the interaction variable from the second option:

```
test2$class <- with(test2, factor(class, levels=unique(class)))

ggplot(test2, aes(x=type, y=value))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=treattype, color=treattype), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), size=3)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se, shape=treattype, color=treattype),
                width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","darkgreen","brown")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17,16,17)) +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales="free_y")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour=NA)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "treatment x type",
                               override.aes = list(colour = c("blue","red","darkgreen","brown"),
                                                   shape = c(16,17,16,17))),
         shape = FALSE)
```

this results in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for the quick reply and great tip. Small adjustment, I would like to have the order few high, few low, many high and many low, and ideally a slightly larger gap between the two 'few' points and the two 'many' points. Can I likewise use the interaction function to generate this order of points? Many thanks

Comment: @tabtimm Yes, that possible. You just have to change the order of the two variables inside the `interaction` function. See the updated answer.

Comment: @tabtimm To get a larger gap, you can increase the dodge-width (e.g. to `0.8`), but that will also increase the width between the high and low points. The latter is a result of the use of the `interaction` function.

Comment: @tabtimm I've added two other options to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked, I know, but I would *strongly* recommend you consider facets for this. It is much less confusing (you avoid the two legends).

```
library(ggplot2)
test2$class <- with(test2,factor(class, levels=unique(class)))
ggplot(test2, aes(x=type, y=value, color=treatment))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), width=0.1, 
                position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~class)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the very helpful suggestions. I like the idea about facets and a single legend. thanks